# React Native text area

Tags: text, react-native

I am trying to display the text(with html quotes from DB => `<p>promotions page</p>`) in react native. I have to display this text without html quotes in react native, `Text` and `TextInput` are not working. Is there is any way?

Comment: Depends on how you want to display? If you want to retain the formatting better to render in a webview. or else you need to parse the html and convert the tags into something that suits your app style.

Comment: i want to view based on the html format like if i have word with html tag <b>tree</b> display word in bold but not with the bold tag

Answer (score 0):

why not use `String.replace('tag', '')`?

Answer (score 0):

I use this package https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview

Example:

```
var html = '<p>promotions page</p>'
var styles = StyleSheet.create({p: { color: <color>}}) 
<HTMLView
  value={html}
  stylesheet={styles}
/>
```